# adjust rigid body objects' position without affecting the whole shape

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I made a logo animation using a rigid body but do not like how the blocks are spread. Moving the blocks one by one did not work because the new position affects how they are gathered together at the end. Is there a way to change the positions of each block when they are on the floor without affecting the final shape, M?

[image]

Just in case you need,
Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihkPV4s9GIScB96JlefOpgUTSIalKrT4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I know my proposals are "another" alternative solution, but maybe it is enough for you.

Instead of moving around them manually you could e.g.

Proposal 1:

- give them another mass and check whether you are satisfied with the new result. To do so: select all cubes, and choose another mass -> and you got new positions

[image]

Proposal 2:

- you manually put other weights to your cubes

Proposal 3:

- this is what you want to do, but it is a LOT OF work.

you can bake your simulation to keyframes. Then you have control over each keyframe of your animation.
you can do it like this:

[image]

But the disadvantage is, that you have to change nearly every position of each keyframe for each cube so that it looks realistic.